# Tannaka duality for C*-algebras?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, ct.category-theory, reference-request

[Tannaka-Krein
duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannaka%E2%80%93Krein_duality) shows
how to recover a group $G$ from its category $\mathbf{Rep}(G)$ of finite-dimensional
complex representations and the forgetful functor $F:\mathbf{Rep}(G)\to
\mathbf{Vect}_{\mathbb{C}}$.

On the other hand, there is [Takesaki's
theorem](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1970350?uid=3739256&uid=369944801&uid=2&uid=3&uid=60&sid=21101931931083)
which shows how to recover a (separable) $C^*$-algebra $A$ from its representation theory. We
have just started looking into the details of this and trying to reformulate this in categorical
terms. It seems tantalizingly similar to the Tannaka-Krein reconstruction
theorem. In particular, it seems that Takesaki secretly also considers natural
transformations from the forgetful functor $F:\mathbf{Rep}(A)\to\mathbf{Hilb}$ to itself.

So, the question is:

> Can Takesaki's duality theorem indeed be formulated in categorical terms similar to Tannaka-Krein duality? Where can we read about it?

We're mostly interested in the unital case. Follow-up question:

> Consider the category of unital $C^*$-algebras and unital completely positive maps. Is there a "nice" description of its opposite as a concrete category?

Answer (score 10):

This isn't an answer but a long comment. Tannaka-Krein duality will mislead you about how hard you should expect this result to be. "Tannaka-Krein duality for rings" is actually very easy and looks like this.

**Theorem:** Let $R$ be a ring. Then $R$ is isomorphic to the endomorphism ring of the forgetful functor $\text{Mod-}R \to \text{Ab}$. (Recall that the category of functors from a category into an $\text{Ab}$-enriched category is $\text{Ab}$-enriched, so endomorphism monoids are rings.)

*Proof.* This functor is represented by the right $R$-module $R_R$, so its endomorphism ring is the endomorphism ring of $R_R$ by the Yoneda lemma. By a second application of the Yoneda lemma (!), the endomorphism ring of $R_R$ is $R$. $\Box$

(And of course if you forget the forgetful functor then you cannot recover $R$ at all, only its Morita equivalence class.)

"Set-theoretic Tannaka-Krein duality for monoids" is also very easy and says that a monoid $M$ is isomorphic to the endomorphism monoid of the forgetful functor $\text{Set-}M \to \text{Set}$; the proof is identical. Tannaka-Krein duality itself is hard because we are considering linear representations of groups, which *a priori* should only let us at best recover the group algebra; we need more structure (e.g. the tensor product) to recover the group itself.

Comment: Thanks for this, that's a good start. Those Yoneda lemma applications are incredibly sneaky!

Comment: Have you checked to see how far the nLab entry on Tannaka Duality (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Tannaka+duality) takes you?

Comment: The same construction works for C*-algebras, except that one should work in the bicategory of C*-categories, C*-functors, and natural transformations.  Specifically, Hilbert C*-modules over a given C*-algebra form a C*-category.  Hilbert spaces also form a C*-category and the C*-algebra of endomorphisms of the forgetful functor is canonically isomorphic to the original C*-algebra.